# How to delete AWS CloudWatch alarm during EC2 termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to delete attached AWS CloudWatch alarm of an EC2 instance during the termination and also based on specific tags. Because we will have large number of EC2 in our account.

**Example:** I would like to delete CloudWatch alarm of EC2 instances during its termination which has Tag (`name:id,Value:123`).

Comment: You can delete alarms by calling `delete_alarms()` on the CloudWatch client and supplying a list of alarm names.

Comment: @John Rotenstein I want to delete it based on specific tag by using aws lambda delete_alarm() will require some manual intervention i am looking for automated solution.